# Apple Shortcut Icon

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I'm pretty sure this is the best site for the this question, if not please feel free to point in a different direction,

I am using the Mac version of Eclipse and I'm stumped as to what the Keyboard Shortcut for "Run as.." is.

The image looks like this:

[image]

I recognize the COMMAND key and the OPTION key, but whats the X key?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the <kbd>X</kbd> on your keyboard.

In [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) you have to press the <kbd>⌥</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> simultaneously and then release all of them and press <kbd>J</kbd>.

Comment: Brilliant! a bit tricky at first, but I'll get use to it, this should save me lots of time, cheers! :)

Answer (score 5):

You hold down <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd> simultaneously, then you press the <kbd>X</kbd> which open a small yellow popup like this:

[image]

where you then press <kbd>J</kbd> - and after that you release <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>.